# Implementing one-tap sign in for interaction with backend

Tags: android, authentication, google-signin, google-identity, google-one-tap

I'm implementing one tap sign in like described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/idtoken-auth) and everything is basically fine(I can get a token, verify it on backend and so on) but I have got one question.
Do I need to store this token locally and send it to backend for every call which requires authentication? And if so how do I refresh it when it expires(because it has exp field and it's basically around hour long)? What is the standard approach to this?
If I don't need to store and send it every time then what should I do instead?
Thanks in advance, I'm new to auth/security related things so sorry for stupid question in advance.

Comment: Similar question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71064941/android-google-one-tap-refresh-token, no answer yet