# Android + Google One Tap Refresh Token?

Tags: android, google-authentication, google-identity, google-one-tap

Whenever I sign in with my Android app using **Google One Tap**, I receive a **TOKEN ID** which is valid for about an hour. How I'm supposed to get a **REFRESH TOKEN** to avoid signing in every hour when that TOKEN **expires**? I've checked the official docs, but there's nothing about REFRESH TOKENS. Does that mean that we need to manually do a sign in (and get a new token) every time that happens?

https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/overview

Comment: There's nothing about it in the documentation. Not sure it's even implemented. Hard to understand why they obsoleted the simple GoogleSignInClient in favor of this convoluted method while leaving parts unimplemented.
Similar question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69931627/implementing-one-tap-sign-in-for-interaction-with-backend

Comment: Have you gone through this StackOverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827920/not-receiving-google-oauth-refresh-token/10857806#10857806)?

Comment: You can manage sessions on your backend, these sessions could have any timeout. But any session should have expiration time. So the question is, how to get a new token without the client?